# How do I sort my text file in python into numerical order? my code sorts it alphabetically, why? (i am new to coding)

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code, would you be able to tell me where I have gone wrong? I want to be able to sort my list numerically so I can make a leader board, for a game I am making. This is a test so that the code doesn't mess up my real code.

```
 text_file = open("write.txt","a")
text_file.truncate(0)

def write():
    global text_file
    text_file.write("Sam has, 7")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Tina has, 32")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Joshua has, 105")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Kathryn has, 8")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.close()
write()
with open("write.txt", 'r') as file:
        list2 = []
        for line in file:
            list2.append(line[0:-1].split(","))

print(list2)
print("")
sorted_lines = sorted(list2, key = lambda x : x[-1] )
print(sorted_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

> my code sorts it alphabetically, why?"

You've never converted anything to an integer, so `list2` is a list of lists that contain strings.

You can do, for example:

```
sorted(list2, key = lambda x: int(x[-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working now (how could I be so dumb)

Answer (score 0):

Run this one !

```
text_file = open("write.txt","a")
text_file.truncate(0)

def write():
    global text_file
    text_file.write("Sam has, 7")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Tina has, 32")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Joshua has, 105")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("Kathryn has, 8")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.close()

write()

with open("write.txt", 'r') as file:
  list2 = []
  leaderBoard = []
  for line in file: 
    if line.lower().find("has, "):
      numStart = line.lower().split("has, ")
      num = numStart[1].replace("\n","")
      leaderBoard.append([[int(num), line]])


leaderBoard.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print(leaderBoard)
```

The output is:

```
[[[7, 'Sam has, 7\n']], [[8, 'Kathryn has, 8\n']], [[32, 'Tina has, 32\n']], [[105, 'Joshua has, 105\n']]]
```